# why virtualenv (version 20) is much faster than python3 -m venv

Tags: python, python-3.x, virtualenv, python-venv

I have tested on my 2015 macbook, `virtualenv` is 6 times faster.

`virtualenv` version is 20.0.21

```
$ time virtualenv $RANDOM
created virtual environment CPython3.8.3.final.0-64 in 340ms
  creator CPython3Posix(dest=/private/tmp/4997, clear=False, global=False)
  seeder FromAppData(download=False, pip=latest, setuptools=latest, wheel=latest, via=copy, app_data_dir=/Users/noname/Library/Application Support/virtualenv/seed-app-data/v1.0.1)
  activators BashActivator,CShellActivator,FishActivator,PowerShellActivator,PythonActivator,XonshActivator

real    0m0.489s
user    0m0.269s
sys     0m0.283s
```

```
$ time /usr/local/opt/python@3.8/bin/python3 -m venv $RANDOM

real    0m3.112s
user    0m2.334s
sys     0m0.731s
```

python3.8 is installed via homebrew.

even with `--creator venv --always-copy` options, `virtualenv` is faster:

```
$ time virtualenv --creator venv --always-copy $RANDOM
created virtual environment CPython3.8.3.final.0-64 in 418ms
  creator Venv(dest=/private/tmp/28878, clear=False, global=False, describe=CPython3Posix)
  seeder FromAppData(download=False, pip=latest, setuptools=latest, wheel=latest, via=copy, app_data_dir=/Users/noname/Library/Application Support/virtualenv/seed-app-data/v1.0.1)
  activators BashActivator,CShellActivator,FishActivator,PowerShellActivator,PythonActivator,XonshActivator

real    0m0.554s
user    0m0.316s
sys     0m0.309s
```

why don't they have the same performance?

Comment: To compare with _venv_ I believe you should use: `virtualenv --seeder pip --creator venv $RANDOM`

Comment: @sinoroc thanks for pointing out `--seeder` option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I understood most of the difference is due to the different methods used to provision the newly created virtual environments.

In February 2020 the version 20 of *virtualenv* was released, it was a full rewrite. And with it came the new concept [called *seeders*](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/user_guide.html#seeders), those define the different methods to provision the environments, i.e. make things such as *pip* and *setuptools* available in the environment. Current versions of *virtualenv* have two seeders:

- *pip* which is probably similar to what *venv* and earlier versions of *virtualenv* do.
- *app-data*, the current default seeder, which uses a different mechanism and is probably the larger contributor to the speed improvements.

From the documentation:

> `app-data` - this method uses the user application data directory to create install images. These images are needed to be created only once, and subsequent virtual environments can just link/copy those images into their pure python library path (the `site-packages` folder). This allows all but the first virtual environment creation to be blazing fast (a `pip` mechanism takes usually 98% of the virtualenv creation time, so by creating this install image that we can just link into the virtual environments install directory we can achieve speedups of shaving the initial 1 minutes 10 seconds down to just 8 seconds in case of copy, or 0.8 seconds in case symlinks are available - this is on Windows, Linux/macOS with symlinks this can be as low as 100ms from 3+ seconds).

You can also read a bit more technical details in this discussion:

- https://discuss.python.org/t/virtualenv-20-0-0-beta1-is-available/3077

Answer (score 0):

Virtualenv 20.x simply has optimizations and tricks up its sleeve that makes it faster; `venv` the standard library module doesn't have those, and probably won't get them either.

Comment: I would be very curious to see a few of these optimizations and trick enumerated.